# Show only a specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select

```
Date1 = '01.01.2024';
Date2 = 'SYS_CURRENTDATE';

SELECT SCHDATE 
FROM mytable
WHERE SCHDATE >= Date1
  AND SCHDATE < Date2;
```

Result:

```
01.01.2024 00:00:00
01.01.2024 08:00:00
01.01.2024 16:00:00
02.01.2024 00:00:00
02.01.2024 08:00:00
02.01.2024 16:00:00
```

I want it to return only the data at 16:00 for all days.

For example:

```
01.01.2024 16:00:00
02.01.2024 16:00:00
03.01.2024 16:00:00
04.01.2024 16:00:00
```

Comment: What is the data type for the `schdate` column?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Datetıme

Comment: Ambiguous dates aside MDY/DMY ... I couldn't get past Date2 = 'SYS_CURRENTDATE';

Comment: SYS_CURRENTDATE='16.02.2024 20:47:00' databese tıme formatıng

Comment: It should really be `SET Date2 = SYSDATETIME();` .....

Comment: If schdate is date time the query should throw up straight away (conversion failed). Or it isn't SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to truncate the values down to just the date, add 16 hours, and group by the result.

I'd show the code, but we don't know that exact data type and there are indications this could be a (shudders) varchar value masquerading at a datetime (don't do that!). The exact type you have here **will**  change what the code needs to look like.

I'll also say, whatever type you have, *do not use string manipulation to do this*. Thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, string manipulation is almost always the slowest and most error-prone way to do date operations. If you do have a varchar, parse it into a real date or datetime value first, and do the operations on that. Then let the client code or reporting tool worry about final formatting.

Comment: How can I separate and group by hour?

Comment: `Dateadd(hour, 16, cast(cast(SCHDATE as date) as datetime)`